# GetFieldValueAsText DATE plus 1 hour

Tags: date-time

I have a GetFieldValueAsText converting DATETIME with 1 hour plus:

29/01/2014 14:26:45 after GetFieldValueAsText I get 29/01/2014 15:26

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: you should really add more information. Where are you using this code? What kind of application is it? What is the local time of the server?

Comment: can you show some code? it would vastly help where your going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint internally stores dates in UTC format.
I think your issue can be related to this:

> The GetFieldValueAsText method requires that date and time values be
>   in UTC format, while most SharePoint Foundation methods for returning
>   list data return the values in local time. Consequently, when
>   performing queries for list data, you need to convert time values to
>   get expected results. To return items in UTC date and time, use an
>   SPQuery object and set the DatesInUtc property to true

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.DatesInUtc = true;
SPListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);
```

See more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442266.aspx

Answer (score 0):

rather than using the spfield object to get the vaule do:

```
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPList myList = web.Lists["My List"];
                SPListItemCollection itemCollection = myList.Items;

                foreach (SPListItem item in itemCollection)
                {
                    DateTime dt = (DateTime)item["dateField"];

                    string showDate = dt.AddHours(1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                }
```